# Plotting data with four variables; two labels for one of the axes

Tags: plotting, variable

I am having difficulty related to 3D plotting task. I have a set of data points in the following form :

```
data={{1x, {1y1,1y2},1z}, {2x,{2y1,2y2},2z},....{nx,{ny1,ny2},nz}}
```

The set of points (1x...nx) and (1z...nz) correspond to the values labelled on the x and z axis as usual. On the other hand the points (1y1,...,ny1) and (1y2,..,ny2) represent two independent parameters to be labelled on y-axis. I would like to include all the points in the data above either by using `ListPlot3D` or `ListPointPlot3D` functions. Is there a way to do it?  More precisely, considering the 3D bounding box for `List3DPlot` (or `ListPointPlot3D`) , I would like to show the points {1y1...ny1} and {1y2...ny2} in the plot such that they are labelled on y-axis; on opposite sides of x-y plane. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: One obvious way to plot 4 parameters in 3D is to use a color scale for the fourth parameter.  However, it is up to you to decide, how it is better to do it depending upon the sense of the plot. I might propose the idea to plot `{x,(y1+y2)/2,z} ` as a 3D point and `(y1-y2)/2 `as a color. Check Menu/Help/DocumentationCenter/Plot3D/Options/PlotLegends to see how the color code can be added.